# How to get sellers PayPal account from eBay transaction

Tags: paypal, ebay-api

How can I get a sellers PayPal email account after I've successfully purchased an item on eBay?

I'm writing an application which makes a purchase on eBay via its API. When it successfully purchases, I receive a Transaction ID from eBay.

I now want to use the PayPal API to pay for this item, and require the sellers email address. I understand that their API has methods like **GetTransactionDetails**, but I'm making the request as a buyer, and also only have the eBay transaction ID.

Where can I get the seller's PayPal email address?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API based approach to remitting purchases on eBay via PayPal.

After testing many different options and wading through the vast mess of eBay API "documentation" and raw responses, it's evident that the PayPal email address of the seller is NOT available unless you are the seller.

Trying to access this field as the buyer, despite being part of the transaction, will simply return "Invalid Data" in this field.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using the PlaceOffer call (from the Trading API) to purchase the item.

You can get the seller's email address using the [GetItemTransactions](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/Reference/eBay/GetItemTransactions.html) API, and there would be a strong liklihood that that email address would be the same one associated with their PayPal account, but it's not guaranteed to be the same. For example, for large-volume sellers, they might have "sales@mystore.com" for their eBay contact but "payments@mystore.com" for their PayPal one.

Comment: Thanks, what you said makes a lot of sense. however based on the risk of paying an incorrect account/not making a successful payment, it's best to find other ways